# How to set up a hook in a github repo when file is changed?

Tags: git, github

My team uses GitHub to host a remote git repository.
I want to notify every team member of changes that were done to a specific file. How can I achieve this?

I looked at GitHub event hooks, but they seem to be capable only of sending HTTP messages to a given host when certain events happen, e.g. https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent.
So this approach requires to set up a message processing service which is way too complicated.

I also looked at git hooks and they seem promising, but have certain limitations:

- bound to the local repo, do not get committed, i.e. need to add them manually to the remote host
- written as shell scripts, i.e. can do only things that are allowed on this host.

Notification type could be anything, but probably email is the easiest.

Use case example: notify every team member by email that common file with error codes has been updated in the master branch of a common project.
If it is not possible to fetch the list of recipients from the GitHub repo, it could be hardcoded.

Comment: github only allows webhooks. You can't add githooks to github, so you would in both cases need to set up something other than github.

Comment: *written as shell scripts* Local hooks can be written in any language — C, go, Python, JavaScript, anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using github.com for your hosting, then there isn't a way to install hooks; you have to use webhooks. If you're using GitHub Enterprise Server (the on-premises version), you can use `pre-receive` hooks, but they aren't ideal for this purpose; you'd really want a `post-receive` hook, because there are reasons the push might be rejected and you wouldn't want to notify people needlessly.

However, there is a service, [smee.io](https://smee.io), which allows you to point your webhooks at a particular endpoint and run a client on a server you control to receive those hooks. You can point the GitHub webhooks there and then have a client which sends emails to whomever you want when you receive a response. The default smee client proxies to a local port, but you can probably modify it to run a given command instead.